# array address do not increment correctly in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to make a recursive function to print the content of an array.
The main looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int s_index;
int main(void) { int even[] = {2, 4, 6, 8}; s_index = 0; print(even);}
```

The print function looks like this:

```
void print(int * array) {
    if(s_index > 3) {
        printf("\n"); return;
    }
    printf(" %d ", *array); ++s_index; print(array + s_index);
}
```

What I notice is:

if `&even` is `0x7fffffffdbf0` then `(array + s_index)` increments as follow with `s_index`:

```
s_index = 0 : 0x7fffffffdbf0;
s_index = 1 : 0x7fffffffdbf4;
s_index = 2 : 0x7fffffffdbfc;
```

it should be `0x7fffffffdbf8`!!?

It is blowing my mind, could someone help with that?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: OMG that global variable. Why not a parameter?

Comment: is you machine 32 bit or 64 bits

Comment: `*array` --> `*(array+s_index)` and `print(array + s_index);` --> `print(array);`

Comment: or, more recursiveish; `print(array + 1)`

Comment: @Magnus Hoff: That wouldn't work. It has to be s_index that's incremented, or the if clause will break.

Comment: @PacMan-- `s_index` is incremented in a separate statement.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It is not a global variable, since it is declared as static. It has local scope. But in this case it seems indeed like a parameter would be preferred.

Comment: @Lundin well yeah, it's scoped to the translation unit. For me, that's "global". It's just as bad as if it wasn't `static` modulo the chance of name collisions.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It is not necessarily bad. It avoids passing around many copies of the same variable all down the recursion. But of course, using recursion just to print some values like this, is already an incredibly bad idea. So everything that is good programming practice was already thrown out through the front door anyway...

Comment: @Magnus Hoff: I see what you mean; you're right. But another thing is that recursion is absolutely not recommended if the program is only going to print numbers wrapping every 3rd number. If there's more to the story; I understand, however in a simple case like the above, it would be much better with a while-loop, only one argument and no global variable.

Comment: @Lundin I totally agree with you. In fact what I am trying to do is build some segmentation fault cases to train some newcomers :) on code refactoring and debugging ;).

Comment: @AlexDavide Well... you should probably not teach newcomers (or anyone else) recursion unless you are having a course about computer search/sort algorithms and binary trees.

Answer (score 2):

You made a logical mistake in your recursive call. See what happens:

Assume `&even = 0x7fffffffdbf0`
First call:
`array = 0x7fffffffdbf0 ; s_index = 0`.
You increase `s_index` and pass into the second call `array + s_index`, which yields:
Second call:
`array = 0x7fffffffdbf4 ; s_index = 1`.
Again, you increase `s_index` and pass into the third call `array + s_index`, which yields:
`array = (0x7fffffffdbf4) + 2 => 0x7fffffffdbfc`

You should only increase array by 1 for each recursive call, and remove `s_index` completely (that's the point of the recursion, to get rid of global variables)

Comment: Of course, getting rid of `s_index` would mean also introducing another termination criterion, for example a `length` parameter, and then calling `print(array + 1, length - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please get rid of the global value s_index.Change your func signature as shown below

```
int main(void)
{ 
   int even[] = {2, 4, 6, 8,10,12}; 
   print(even,(sizeof(even)/sizeof(int)));
}

void print(int * array,int len) {
    if( len == 0) 
    {
        printf("\n"); return;
    }
    else
    {
    printf(" %d ", *(array)); 
    print(array+1,len-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, indeed it is a logical mistake. However the else do not solve anything. I just changed it to print(++array).

Comment: Fixes the problem, but the global variable, although not causing anything wrong, needs to be killed with fire

Comment: @Rerito Agree but pointed out what is going wrong in the written code

Comment: @Gopi Without any explanation or advice. You should make your answer more ... enlightening :)

Comment: @Rerito there you have it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do really strange and obscure things for no apparent reason, such as using recursion where simple loops are faster, safer and more readable. Because when you are doing really strange things on purpose, other equally strange things tend to happen unexpectedly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int* array, size_t size) 
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    printf("value:%d address:%p\n", array[i], (void*)&array[i]);
  }
}

int main(void) 
{ 
  int even[] = {2, 4, 6, 8}; 
  print(even, 4);
}
```